# Label edges of `fgl` graph based on directives

Tags: haskell, graph

Currently, I have the following data type (call it a directive),

```hs
data type = Up (a -> Bool) | Down (a -> bool)
```

And given a list of directives, I would like to apply/add edge. For example,

```hs
([Up (\_ -> True)], "parent")
```

Should add edge `(a, b, "parent")`, where `a` and `b` are the last two nodes in the traversal based on directive.

Another example,

```hs
([Up (\_ -> True), Up (\a -> sex a == "male")], "grandfather")
```

My aim is to label edges relative to some rooted node. For example, an edge between parent node's and its parent is labelled `grandparent` so it is relative to some rooted node. I have attempted to use `gfold` which has an argument `Context a b -> [Node]` to determine which nodes to visit but could not understand it.